# Why Maxint and Minint are inverted in my Golang exercise?

Tags: go

I was trying to find max and min of some ints by using this

```
    min, max = math.MinInt64, math.MaxInt64

    if n > max {
        max = n
        }
    if n < min {
        min = n
    }
```

But when I checked the solution, the values were inverted

```
   min, max = math.MaxInt64, math.MinInt64
```

Can anyone explain me this concept in a simple way. Thanks

Comment: What exercise? What are you trying to do?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense without context... What is `n`?

Comment: it's a common technique to put in the "opposite" initial value for `max` or `min` - so when iterating a list the first iteration is guaranteed to replace the `max` (or `min`) value. Then future iterations will compare `max` (or `min`) with that iterated value and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing to explain here, it might be a simple mistake in the solution.  Value of math.MinInt64 is stored in min and math.MaxInt64 is stored in max

If your code doesn't give proper results share your code and test cases.

See [Short Variable Declarations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

Also if n is of type Int64 then the condition

```
n > max
```

or

```
n < min
```

could never be satisfied as n would be out of bounds for Int64.
The value of n will always lie between min and max, i.e.

> math.MinInt64 < n < math.MaxInt64